# Как вернуть последовательность id в django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model, django-filter

Столкнулся с эстетической проблемой, после удаления объекта с id=6 из БД sqlite3, следующие объекты уже шли с id=7 и т.д, то есть перепрыгивая id=6. Есть ли какая-то Django orm команда чтобы вернуть эту последовательность id чисел?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ответ с англ. Stackoverflow: [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735494/10090254)

> Вы должны понимать, что это желаемое поведение. ID однозначно
> идентифицирует объект в вашей базе данных. Это значит, что он должен
> ссылаться только на одну строку. Если эта строка будет удалена, значит
> нет причин, по которым эта новая строка должна повторно использовать
> этот идентификатор. Если вы это сделаете - вы создадите путаницу между
> удаленным объектом и новым. В этом нет смысла, и это не нужно делать.